# Dropdown auto populate into text on a page (non-input field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a dropdown choice populate multiple selections, but not as an input field.

Here is an example as input fields, but I am not sure how to alter this to make just text on a page via [strong] / [div] or something.

http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/

```
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids[0] = "";
use[0] = "";
ful[0] = "";

ids[1] = 6;
use[1] = "bsmith";
ful[1] = "Buddy Smith";

ids[2] = 2;
use[2] = "lsmith";
ful[2] = "Libbie Smith";

ids[3] = 4;
use[3] = "asmith";
ful[3] = "Andy Smith";


    function Choice() {
        //x = document.getElementById("users");
        y = document.getElementById("selectUsers");

          //x.value = y.options[y.selectedIndex].text;
          document.getElementById("ids").value = ids[y.selectedIndex];
          document.getElementById("use").value = use[y.selectedIndex];
          document.getElementById("ful").value = ful[y.selectedIndex];
     }

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<select id="selectUsers" name="users" onChange='Choice();'><option> </option>
<option value="1">bsmith</option>
<option value="2">lsmith</option>
<option value="3">asmith</option>
</select>
<p>ids <input type="text" id="ids" name="id" ></p>
<p>use <input type="text" id="use" name="username" ></p>
<p>ful <input type="text" id="ful" name="full_name" ></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any element instead of `<input />`, for example a `<span />`. The difference is you set its `.innerHTML`[1], not `.value`, so use

```
<p>ids <span id="ids"></span></p>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("ids").innerHTML = ids[y.selectedIndex];
```

to set the HTML of an element instead of value of an input.

http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/171/

[1] innerText/textContent would be a better choice, but it could introduce unnecessary complexity

Answer (score 1):

use `innerHtml` property of the dom element

```
document.getElementById("ids").innerHTML = ids[y.selectedIndex];
```

Details:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize the array the way you have done then instead of setting each array item individually you can set it as below.

```
var ids = new Array();
var use = new Array();
var ful = new Array();

ids=["",6,2,4];
use=["","bsmith","lsmith", "asmith"];
ful=["","Buddy Smith","Libbie Smith", "Andy Smith"]
```

Other than this my answer is not much different than what pawel suggested, but its a bit of a cleaner solution... its not great code by any mean but it's a good piece considering that you are beginner and i wouldn't like to make it too complex. Enjoy coding :) => http://jsfiddle.net/zunrk/172/

Comment: Thank you, this works great on PC, but for some reason neither yours or what pawel suggested work on iOS. (thats kind of what i was needing it for)

Comment: Never mind, it was a jfiddle issue, once I added it to my site it worked fine with jQuery Mobile.